# Run cygwin command from windows command line

Tags: command-line, cygwin, rsync

I am trying to make PhpStorm run `vagrant rsync` when files are changed, because built-in `rsync-auto` fails with my deep directory structure. I am able to setup watcher in PhpStorm settings, but I don't know how to run it correctly. There problem is that when I run `vagrant up` or `vagrant rsync` from windows command line, I am getting different errors from wrong path to arguments issues, so I decided to run it under cygwin and it works now. So, I need a solution to run cygwin from command line and execute command in it.

What I tried:

```
C:/cygwin/bin/bash vagrant rsync
```

Getting error:

```
C:\Program Files\Vagrant\embedded\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb (LoadError)
```

Tried:

```
bash vagrant rsync
```

Error:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receive
r=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=
3.1.1pre1]
```

Trying to find out why output is different:

```
C:\>where bash
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
```

So msysgit is used in second case.

Command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty -e vagrant sync
```

Output: nothing. Window opens and closes immediately.

Answer (score 8):

Use c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe to launch cygwin processes from windows cmd.exe

Comment: that works great but doesn't show the output.  To show the output use ```C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash --login -c '/usr/bin/rsync'```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `bash` command with the `--login` & `-c` options to launch Cygwin processes from Windows and see the output.

ie. `C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash --login -c 'whoami'`

Comment: to add, if you want the cygwin to start in your current directory instead of the home directory, you can pass in the current directory using `%cd%`. for example: `C:/cygwin64/bin/bash --login -c 'cd "%cd%"; ls'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to launch socat in cygwin with extra PATH.

You may also do `shell:startup` in run, and put shortcut into startup folder, then it will run automatically when you login

launch_socat.cmd

```
@echo off
rem start with extra path
cmd.exe  /c "path=D:\Tools\Cygwin\bin;%path% & D:\Tools\Cygwin\bin\bash --login -c '/cygdrive/d/WebServer/start_socat.sh'"

pause
```